# How to add combination pick-list in any object of salesforce (Standard Fields of object does not meet requirement )

Tags: apex, fields, custom, system-fields

I am new to Salesforce, so i am asking for your suggestion here.

How to add combination pick-list in any object of salesforce (Standard Fields of object does not meet requirement ).

I have two picklist , i want to select both pick list and want to store the combination of two separated with "-" in another field.

Also , if one combination is selected , it will be disabled after selecting once.

I have tried to use , Apex page in between the "New Contact" creation form.

My idea was to create apex page , with custom javascript and custom select/ multiselectbox.

and pushing the Combination value in HIDDEN textbox of salesforce field.

picture below will give more clear idea about my requirement.

[image]

I have tried and made efforts to solve this issue, as mentioned in the original question **"I have tried to use , Apex page in between the "New Contact" creation form."**

Below apex code of my custom APEX page.

and out put of apex page is here.
[image]

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="contactExtension">

<h1>PRAGNESH</h1>
<select name="prags" id="prags" >
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="HRR">HRR</option>
<option value="AR">AR</option>
<option value="SR">SR</option>
</select>


<select name="prags_in" id="prags_in" onchange="test_child()">
<option value="">-Select-</option>
<option value="Manual">Manual</option>
<option value="Categorized">Categorized</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="output" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function test(x) {

   // var x = document.getElementById(x).options[document.getElementById(x).selectedIndex].text

  //  document.getElementById('output').value = x;

}//end of function

function test_child() {

    var x = document.getElementById('prags').value;

     var x1 = document.getElementById('prags_in').value;
     alert('x : '+x);

     alert('x1 : '+x1);

    document.getElementById('output').value = x+"-"+x1;

}//end of function
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Code of APEX CLASS is as below

```
global class contactExtension{

    public Contact c {get;set;}
    public ContactExtension(Apexpages.standardController sc)
    {
    c = (Contact)sc.getRecord();
    }

}
```

My thinking was to add this custom apex page in between "NEW CONTACT" creation form.

I went to Setup->Contacts->Page Layout
 and i have put APEX PAGE in between the FORM as per below image.

[image]

**Just wanted to know , i am on right direction?
Or any other solution for that.**

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: Please elaborate on the disabling of a combination requirement.  Can a user select multiple combinations over time for the same record?

Comment: Modified question

Comment: Any help further??

Comment: Pragnesh -- in general, folks at SFSE like to see a good faith effort at some apex/vf as they don't want to be providers of free labor

Comment: I already tried and made efforts to solve this issue. Just forgot to mention my code in question. Please suggest me is i am going in right direction OR any other way to solve this issue.

Comment: Edited the original post with extra information , and solution which i tried to solve this issue.

Comment: Why not to use two dependent multiselect picklists and one formula field that saves a combination?

Comment: Mast0r : Can you please explain in more details ? With some example.

Comment: @mast0r : I want to add Combination Picklist , with some logic on Creation of Contact Layout Page.

I want a different way , by which this is possible.

I have tried with putting , static SelectBOX and some jquery code , and tried to include that on Layout of Contact Add.





Logic is only , Selectbox 1 value should not be repeated (used only once), however you can use selectbox 2 value again and again.

Diagram above for combination picklist will help you to understand it in more details.